# Sorting an array of type Object

Tags: java, compare

I need to write a method which sorts (merge sort) an array of Objects and has this exact signature:

`void mergeSort(Object[] a)`

Generics are not allowed at all.

The method will be passed a covariant array, ex: `String[]` or `Integer[]` . My problem now is that I don't know how to access a Comparator of these Objects or sort them otherwise without one. The algorithm for sorting the elements itself is not the problem.

Comment: Since hashCode() is an object method, you might be able to sort on that. I assume this is for a class.

Comment: Your intension is quite contraversional. You want to avoid generics, but create method for general case for any class. For sorting you need Comparator<T> instance as second parameter of the method, or array of Comparable<T> as first and only parameter, both use generics.

Comment: I'm very aware of that, unfortunately that is how the exercise is formulated. We've just handled generics in class, but I've asked and I'm not allowed to use them.

This is the whole question if it helps at all:

Write a method void mergeSort(Object[] a) for sorting an array a of objects into 
ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements using the 
mergesort algorithm. You can use lists or arrays as a buffer. Test MergeSort with 
String objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the task is designed to show you how awful things were before generics, because this is exactly how the Java <1.5 signature for sorting an array would look like :)

Since the task says "natural ordering", it's implied that the passed Object implements the `Comparable` interface which has a method `compareTo()`. So to access it you should simply cast the `Object` to `Comparable`. This is exactly what they say in Java 1.4.2 documentation: [https://www2.cs.duke.edu/csed/java/jdk1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])](https://www2.cs.duke.edu/csed/java/jdk1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object%5B%5D))

The key idea behind generics is that when you try to pass, say, a Cactus object into a `sort()` method, it would fail in compile time, rather than throw a `ClassCastException` in runtime when JVM would try to cast the Cactus class to `Comparable` interface.

Comment: This actually worked! I had no idea you could even cast to an interface. I figured it would need to implement ```Comparable``` to have a "natural order", but didn't know where to go from there without generics. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void mergeSort(Object[] array) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Comparator<Object> comparator = (Comparator<Object>)Comparator.naturalOrder();
    Arrays.sort(array, comparator);  // Or your own sort logic with `comparator`
}
```

and

```
String[] stringArray = {"c", "d", "b", "a", "e"};
mergeSort(stringArray);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringArray));

[a, b, c, d, e]


Integer[] integerArray = {5, 3, 2, 4, 1};
mergeSort(integerArray);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integerArray));

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


Object[] objectArray = {new Object(), new Object(), new Object()};
mergeSort(objectArray);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(objectArray));

java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable...


Object[] mixedArray = {"c", 2, "a", "b", 1, 3};
mergeSort(mixedArray);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mixedArray));

java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer...
```